# How do I invoke a php routine from jquery and then act on the results

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to query a database in real time to verify that a number entered is unique.

Here is my php to construct the html.

```
echo "<form action=create_materials.php method=post>";
echo "<table border=0 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=2 align=center>";
echo "<tr><td></td><td><input type=hidden size=20 name=action value=\"addupdate\"></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td></td><td><input type=hidden size=20 name=subcreatematerial value=\"1\"></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td></td><td><input type=hidden size=20 name=prodid value=" . $product['prodid'] . "></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td></td><td><input type=hidden size=20 name=id value=" . $product['prodtype'] . "></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td><input type=text size=10 id = 'cubcode' name=cubcode value = '".$form->value("cubcode")."'></td><td>".$form->error("user")."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td class=tabclearleft><b>Description</b></td><td><input type=text size=50 name=description value = '".$form->value("description")."'></td></tr>";
...
echo "<tr><td></td><td><input type=submit border=0 value=\"Submit\"></td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
```

and this is my jquery.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$('#cubcode').focusout(function() {
        var cubcode = $(this).val();
    $.post('checkcubcode.php', { cubcode: cubcode }, function(data){
        if (data == '0') {
            alert("Successful");
                }
        else  {
            alert ('Failed');
            }   
        });
    });                             
});


</script>
```

finally, this is the php code that i am calling from the jquery

```
include("include/session.php");


function mysql_evaluate($query, $default_value=0) {
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result ||mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        return $default_value;
    }
else {
    return mysql_result($result, 0);
    }
    }

    if ($_POST && isset($_POST['cubcode'])) {

        // sanitize the value
        $cubcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cubcode']);

        // start the query
        $sql = "select count(*) from materials where cubcode = '".$cubcode."'";
        $result = mysql_evaluate($sql);

        return $result;
    }
```

Neither of the alerts is being activated when I tab out of the cubcode text box

Comment: Add an alert before you send the post-request and check if your eventlistener is called.

Comment: Or install firebug and see if you can see the ajax call in the console.

Comment: firebug is telling me I have problems with the format of the jquery, but it is not obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in your code it has the line return $result; however it is not in any specific function and it will not output the result if you are using the return keyword.

[PHP Manual: return](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)

You need to add an echo command to output the result. Otherwise nothing will be displayed.

```
echo $result;
```

[PHP Manual: echo](https://www.php.net/echo)

Another thing I noticed about the JavaScript code you added. It has an extra closing parenthesis at the end.

```
);
```

should be removed

Both Google Chrome and Firefox have good tools for catching those kind of errors. Use developer tools on google chrome and Firebug on Firefox to help you verify your code. There are also a number of Javascript Linters such as JSLint that can be integrated with different development environments that can help you verify things such as that.

Comment: Thanks. I had originally used echo but in my desperation I tried return

Comment: I removed the ');'.  I can see that the script is being triggered by the focusout event but it does not seem to come back to process the if statement.

Comment: Try placing some code to echo out 1 and then exit from the script in between your if statement that checks the post data. 
`if ($_POST && isset($_POST['cubcode'])) {
    echo 1; exit;
    ...` 

If it gets that far then you can know that the file being included is working and that it is detecting the data posted to the server.

Comment: Thanks i found my error and it is working correctly now.  Thanks to everyone for their help.